# setVisible(true) no funciona

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo este codigo pero se muestran los paneles (que por defecto estan false) cuando los pongo true.

```
boton1.addActionListener(e -> {
switch (tipo){
                case "1","2","3":
                    panel1.setVisible(true);
                case "4":
                    panel2.setVisible(true);
                    boton2.addActionListener(v -> {
                        if (contraseña.equals(Clase1.contraseña)){
                            panel3.setVisible(true);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Intentalo de nuevo",
                                    "Código Incorrecto",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    });
            }
}
```

Sé que el evento está funcionando porque he imprimido en pantalla para comprobar que sí está funcionando

Comment: "se muestran ... cuando los pongo true" así es el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: corrección: No se muestran cuando los pongo true.